# Quam as a temporal conjunction vs adverb of extent

Tags: grammar-identification

In the following sentence from Historia Augusta:

*si quidem tantae luxuriae fuisse dicitur ut etiam, quam de Syria rediit, popinam domi instituerit,...*

Should I interpret quam as a temporal conjunction ("**when** he returned from Syria he installed a tavern in his house") or should it be treated as an adverb of extent ("after he returned from Syria, he **went so far as to have** installed a tavern in his house")

Answer (score 2):

The line is corrupt and has been emended. P, i.e. Codex Palatinus 899, our primary manuscript for the *Historia Augusta*, has *quam postea*, but some editors prefer to read it as *posteaquam*,a word  which is not only common in the *Historia Augusta*, but also frequently corrupt therein.